PDAL Plugins - readers.e57
Trying to get the plugins work consistently for PDAL. Here is an error message I get when trying to convert from .e57 to .laz
PDAL: readers.e57: 17 : result=-1 fileName=input.e57 flags=0 mode=0

What causes this? What is the -1 result error code. Docs are not clear on this.
I am already running pdal in their docker container to avoid plugin linkage issues
